# Can't run my project in android studio in my MacBook with M1 Pro chip

Tags: java, android, macos, android-studio, apple-m1

I can't run my Android Studio project on my MacBook Pro with the M1 Pro chip but it does run on Windows and MacBook Pro with an Intel chip.

This is the error I have:

```
    > Task :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED
    Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
    > java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    
    * Try:
    Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

Here is stacktrace result:

        
    FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
    
    * Where:
    Build file '/Users/User/Downloads/FindMeHomeApp-master 2/app/build.gradle'
    
    * What went wrong:
    Could not compile build file '/Users/User/Downloads/FindMeHomeApp-master 2/app/build.gradle'.
    > startup failed:
      General error during conversion: Unsupported class file major version 61
      
      java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 61
      

  at groovyjarjarasm.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:189)
        at groovyjarjarasm.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:170)
        at groovyjarjarasm.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:156)
        at groovyjarjarasm.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:277)
```

---

Here I got a lot of lines started at :

at org.codehaus.

or
at groovy.lang.

or
at org.gradle.

---

```
 at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:56)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
  
      1 error
    
    
    * Try:
    Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
    
    * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
    
    Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0.
    Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
    See https://docs.gradle.org/7.0.2/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
    
    BUILD FAILED in 1s
```

Comment: Stacktrace, that could be useful. Can you provide the output?

Comment: FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file '/Users/User/Downloads/FindMeHomeApp-master 2/app/build.gradle'

* What went wrong:
Could not compile build file '/Users/User/Downloads/FindMeHomeApp-master 2/app/build.gradle'.
> startup failed:
  General error during conversion: Unsupported class file major version 61
 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 61

Comment: Thanks.. what is your gradle version and JDK version?

Comment: gradle version - 7.0.2

Comment: JDK version: (this is the output from java --version in command line)

openjdk 17.0.1 2021-10-19 LTS
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Zulu17.30+15-CA (build 17.0.1+12-LTS)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Zulu17.30+15-CA (build 17.0.1+12-LTS, mixed mode, sharing)

Comment: @Richard Barber I also added more info in my post about the output that I got from stacktrace

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Answer to my question***

Use Room 2.4.0-alpha03 for those who use the M1 /M1 Pro chip.

```
def room_version = "2.4.0-alpha03"
implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:$room_version"
annotationProcessor "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version"
```

Comment: wow, it's work! but why it was showing the databinding error? @@